# NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile doesnt load the data in order

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I am trying to load some data from a plist into an array

```
NSDictionary* mydictionary = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[ [ [ NSBundle      mainBundle] bundlePath ] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyLevels.plist" ] ];

NSMutableArray *panelNames1;                                                         
panelNames1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id theKey in mydictionary) {        
    [panelNames1 addObject:[mydictionary objectForKey:theKey]]; 
}
```

But it does not seem to output in the same order as the MyLevels.plist into the array.

MyLevels.plist looks likes this: 
[Key:1 Value: One]
[Key:2 Value: Two]
[Key:3 Value: Three]
[Key:4 Value: Four]
[Key:5 Value: Five]

But it reads it in this order: Three, One, Four, Two, Five

Any idea why??
Or even another way of doing the for loop maybe so it is in the correct order.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`NSDictionary` objects do not preserve ordering. You should not expect to have keys enumerated in the same order in which they were read.

Comment: @Vasi: If order matters, use an array.

Comment: You should also not expect the enumeration order to be stable in any situation.

Answer (score 2):

If order is important, you should create an array in your plist, and access it from one of the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea why?

Yes. `NSDictionary` is unordered.